# 5 m, 5 V LED strip 20 A PS = Fire?

Tags: led, led-strip, rgb

I've got a 5m LED RGB strip to go up the stairs and will be programming it with arduino.

[eBay link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1m-5m-5V-WS2812B-5050-RGB-30-60LEDs-M-LED-Strip-ws2812-IC-Individual-Addressable/132734477057?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=432045666970&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649).

They state 60 LEDs/m @ 18 watt/meter, thats 3.3 W per LED?

It says current rating of 3 A, so that means I can only power 9 LED's at a time wiring it from both ends?

That doesn't sound right.

By the looks of it if I wired in my 5 V, 20 A supply to both ends it would still set fire.

I've seen these questions asked with some good answers, but I don't understand how the small cables I see people use don't simply go up in flames.

So I would have to run it in batches of 9 LEDs using my calcs, which would be an absolute nightmare, surely I'm wrong.

Comment: My calculator says it is 0.3 watts per LED, not 3.3 watts.

Comment: 0.3 watts as opposed to 3.3? How do you get that? 60/18 is 3.3

Comment: 18 Watts/meter and 60 LEDs/meter.  18 watts divided by 60 LEDS 18/60 = 0.3W/LED

Comment: voting to close because the question is based on simple arithmetic misconception

Comment: Thanks for the help, and also the down vote, been researching it for 2 days and last resort was to ask directly. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They state 60 LEDs/m @ 18 watt/meter, thats 3.3 W per LED?

0.3 W per LED, they're assuming the standard 60 mA per diode for RGB 5050 SMDs.

> By the looks of it if I wired in my 5 V, 20 A supply to both ends it would still set fire.

20 A is how much current the supply can provide, not how much it will actually give when hooked to the load.  Those tiny traces have a lot of resistance, so if you try to hook up 5 m, you will get a lot of voltage drop, many or even most of the LEDs won't turn on and the actual current load will be much lower.  Hence, no fire (and not much light).

To use that many LEDs you will probably have to wire a bunch of shorter strips in parallel, each using a current of a few amps.

Comment: 5m isnt enough to droop enough to not turn on the far end LEDs. They are noticeably dimmer but not enough to be considered off or quarter brightness.  5m is a standard roll too.